# iTunes Connect rejection: 2.2 missing frameworks linking against @rpath/Pods.framework

Tags: xcode, cocoa, app-store-connect, cocoapods

I've received the same rejection twice and I think it's because I don't really know how to fix this link in Xcode. This is the error message:

> The app references frameworks which are missing. This may lead to unexpected bugs or undefined behavior. The missing framework is:
>
> '/Applications/[MyAppName].app/Contents/MacOS/[MyAppName]' which links against: '@rpath/Pods.framework'

Where do I go in Xcode to re-link or fix this? I've tried cleaning/deleting derived data/reinstalling pods and I don't think any of these actions are touching the problem.

Comment: Does the app launch at all when you try it locally on a different machine? Sounds like a typical problem you'll get when launching on the dev machine with locally installed (additional) dev. frameworks/dependencies

Comment: @cacau I haven't tried! Do you mean just to load the repository on a different macbook, build it, and try to run from Xcode?